# Exihibiting an altered form of a code chunk on pdf with R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to know if it is possible to show an altered form of the code below in the pdf

````
```{r}
DATA=read.table("/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/analysis/file.csv", header=T, sep=";")
```
````

The would pdf show something like this:

```
DATA=read.table("/home/.../.../file.csv", header=T, sep=";")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
DATA=read.table("/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/analysis/file.csv", header=T, sep=";")
```

```{r, eval=FALSE}
DATA=read.table("/home/.../.../file.csv", header=T, sep=";")
```
````

This evaluates the first chunk but does not echo it. The second chunk is not evaluated but echo'ed.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, you could have both lines in the same chunk, and use `eval=-2, echo=-1`.